# Can gallons be used for measuring size? And if so - how many inches is it?

Tags: meaning, measuring-units

I have found the following passage in a book.

"Stack 12 (based on the participation of 22 children) **gallon-size**, resealable plastic bags together. Staple them across the bottom to make the binding of the book. Cover the staples with a 2-inch-wide strip of colored vinyl tape. Make a cover for the book (you may want to list children’s names on the back of the cover) and slip it into the first bag. Make a back cover to slip into the last bag. Slip children’s artwork back-to-back into the other bags."

I understand the idea of the *bag book*, but I cannot figure out the "gallon-size" bit. I know there are 2 types of gallon for measuring capacity, but how can it be applied for size? Or am I missing sth obvious here?

Comment: It looks like the volume those bags can hold.

Comment: Well, it does indeed. And that's my problem, because it can't then be 'translated' into traditional measurement systems.

Comment: Are you translating so that someone can make these things, or is it for more formal literary purposes?

Comment: It is for somebody who would like to make it. We get the idea, but I'm wondering about whether there is sth special in the "gallon-size" or it's just a clumsy way of explaining how big the bags should be. In the latter case, we'll just make whatever we see fit :)

Comment: Specifying bag size by their volume is fairly common. In Australia, we might talk about 8L vs 10L bin liners. Using gallons would sound natural and familiar in a country that uses the imperial system.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I checked - it's 12x10 inches. I'm a moron not to have googled it first :) Thanks again. You've been most helpful. (Well, actually, here, the bin liners also are measured with litres...).

Comment: Here in Britain, we buy 'bin liners' (refuse bags) in litre sizes; I can go to Wilko (a chain of stores) and buy a roll of ten 80 litre black bags for £1.60.

Comment: "it's 12x10 inches" - you can make a bag that encloses a 10 gallon volume in an infinite number of 'sizes'.

Comment: In the US, it is the ubiquitous way of differentiating Ziploc bags. The boxes all say 1 Quart, 2 Quarts, 1 Gallon or 2 Gallon on them. You write "gallon bags" on your shopping list. The first Google return for "gallon bag" is an image of a box of Ziploc bags.

Comment: @PhilSweet Precisely. My mind was so focused on the seeming absurdity of describing resealable bags with their capacity that I suspected sth tricky going on there and didn't even think of a simple Google search. As I said before - it was unwise of me :) In my defence - the bags are 2-dimensional. I mean 3-D - physically, but, you know, we do not store liquids in them. It's for drawings or tiny toys. I don't see myself as a proud owner of 2 gallons of little Peppa Pigs :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, of course. But what I was looking for was what the author meant. BTW. 1,60? It's cheap. Were it not for the trouble and the shipping cost, I'd ask you to buy me some :)

Comment: [Wilko](https://www.wilko.com/en-uk/home/household/bins-bin-liners/bin-liners/c/387) are a big UK chain of shops.

Comment: A litre is 1000 cubic centimetres. A gallon is 277 cubic inches, which is 4.54609 litres.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ...or 3,8 l in the US. BTW Here is not the UK :)